# Структура данных на 4 миллиарда элементов

Tags: c#

Мне нужен обычный массив со значениями true/false размерности uint ( > 4млрд), но когда я пытаюсь обратиться к элементу `> int.MaxValue` (хотя обращаюсь по индексу uint), то компилятор выдает ошибку.

> System.OverflowException: "Array dimensions exceeded supported range."

```
uint x = 4000000000;
bool[] b = new bool[x];
Console.WriteLine(b[x - 1].ToString());
```

Насколько я понял, в [clr специально стоит](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47838574/9852582) такое ограничение, но как эту проблему (кроме как подход маршала через небезопасный код) решить я так и не придумал. Какое решение тут можно придумать?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.bitarray, но тоже не поможет.

Comment: пробовал уже, не помогло :) @Qwertiy

Comment: Если нет жесткого требования к использованию готового кода, то своя обертка над списком подмассивов/bitarray'ев? uint индекс преобразовать внутри геттера не проблема, но такой подход потенциально медленнее из-за этих преобразований.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker я пока решил просто разделить данные на 2 булевых массива и объединить их в одной структуре

Comment: Я это и имел в виду, в принципе :) Булевы массивы при таком кол-ве элементов тратят слишком много лишнего места, лучше использовать 2 bitarray вместо массивов.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, не всегда. BitArray будет работать медленнее, так что вопрос что важнее - 3.5 GB памяти или возможное замедление в несколько раз.

Comment: @Qwertiy сильно от алгоритма зависит, в некоторых ситуациях и локальность обращений может повлиять на производительность. Но в целом согласен, BitArray не панацея :)

Answer (score 3):

Сложно просить систему аллоцировать 4 000 000 000 байт (bool занимает 8 бит) подряд.

> Возможно больше, элементы массива могут быть "выравнены" в соответствии с разрядностью процессора, если я не ошибаюсь. Тогда будет (4 миллиона * разрядность процессора) бит подряд.

Такая проблема решается всего одним способом - не просить выделять целый блок памяти, а сегментировать его - проще говоря, **использовать связный список!**
`System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList` не имеет подобных ограничений.

Если нужно больше скорости - можно использовать связный список из массивов по миллиарду элементов, например.

Comment: чем связный список лучше, чем обычный многомерный массив?

Comment: мне нужно не 4млрд байт, а 4млрд элементов

Comment: tym32167, Многомерные массивы всё равно хранятся последовательно. Пруф смогу выложить не раньше чем через пару часов.

Comment: Anton Nikolaev, я понимаю. По классике, bool описывается 8 битами (это ещё со времён C). Что может случиться если упечь их в массив в .Net - я спрятал под спойлер в ответе.

Comment: Возможно, я ошибся, и "выравнивание" касается только структур, а не массивов.

Comment: bool занимает 8 байт вместо 1 не из-за прихоти разработчиков языка Си, а из-за особенностей работы цп.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, может 8 бит?

Comment: @Grundy разумеется, спасибо за правку =)

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, похоже в ответе такая же описка :)

Comment: @Grundy, да. Исправил.

Comment: давайте переформулирую. Чем ваше решение лучше, чем массив массивов?

Comment: @tym32167, массив массивов является эквивалентом связного списка массивов, с той разницей что указатели на вложенные массивы будут храниться строго последовательно [в массиве массивов]. Искать тут фактические преимущества можно только в контексте конкретных алгоритмов работы с этими структурами.

Comment: так я про это и говорю. Связанный список ест больше памяти и не имеет константрого доступа по индексу. Это минусы, а плюсы в данном случае какие?

Comment: Бред какой-то. Только связных списков не хватало. И на x64 найти 4 ГБ непрерывной памяти наверняка довольно просто. А LongCount есть у любой коллекции.

Comment: @Qwertiy, а в чём проблема связных списокв? Разрядность процессора не связана с оперативной памятью. Сложно прогнозировать, как операционная система и рантайм будут разбираться с запросом 4GB памяти, но я почти уверен что в момент появления такого запроса они таки попытаются аллоцировать его целиком - а это всё же не простая задача! С LongCount я ошибся, конечно. Это метод расширения, который определяется в Linq, а не связном списке. Но связный список, так или иначе, не имеет никаких ограничений на размер, кроме количества виртуальной памяти, которое сможет предоставить ОС.

Comment: проблема связанных списков в том, что когда вы знаете нужное вам количество места заранее, вам связанные списки не нужны.

Comment: @tym32167, связный список может содержать столько элементов, сколько влезет в память, массив - столько, сколько влезет в память **подряд**. Это плюс. К времени доступа к n-му элементу чувствительны не все алгоритмы, но я почему-то думаю что векторизовать 4 миллиарда элементов не получится, и их в любом случае придётся обходить поштучно, если требуется обработка всех. __Нужно уточнять у автора детали алгоритма__. Я думаю, что список массивов (а он на данный момент именно так решил проблему, по его словам) на такой задаче имеет все плюсы обоих подходов.

Comment: На самом деле, даже когда вы хотите фрагментировать память, массив массивов решит эту проблему и это решение будет работать быстрее и кушать меньше памяти, чем спязанный список. И это при любом варианте использования этой памяти. Хоть вы последовательно будете от элемента к элементу проходить, хоть по индексу.

Comment: Если мы сравниваем массив 2-х массивов максимального размера и связный список двух массивов то потеря памяти будет - на один указатель, а потеря в вычислениях - 0. Если это не так - прошу уже пруфы. Я реально не вижу разницы между массивом массивов и связным список массивов для данной задачи. Может быть какие-нибудь фрагменты на асаме или исходные коды нас наконец рассудят? Помимо прочего, я всё ещё вижу пробелму: если потребуется 2^32^32 элементов - то это придётся уже решать трёхмерным массивом - придётся переписывать код. Связный список отработает как раньше.

Comment: Ваше сообщение полно противоречий. То вы говорите, что 4гб выделить трудно, но при этом хотите выделить 2гб, думаете это сильно легче? Вы пишете про 2 мпссива, в ответе пишете `Такая проблема решается всего одним способом - ... использовать связный список!` - то есть выделить область памяти на 2 указатея можно только связанным списком? В чем смысл 2 указателей в виде свящанного списка? Вы просите пруфов, что массив работает быстрее, чем связанный список? Откройте любой учебрик по CS. Что делать, если понадобится ещё память (что уже другая задача)? - поглядите имплементацию `List<T>`